# How to set http header on a wsdl2java soap stub?

Tags: java, soap, jira, stub, wsdl2java

I want to set http `cookie` header to my Jira soap stub which is created using wsdl2java. 
I have already checked the link 
http://axis.apache.org/axis/faq.html

but the way suggested on this link is to set a soap header and I want a Http header on the request.

How to do it?

Thanks

Comment: I want some way other than interceptor :) which is mentioned in below link

http://java.dzone.com/articles/adding-http-headers-soap

As with interceptor I loose context and will need to have a thread local variable to figure out which user has fired the request.

This will be the last option that I will use if nothing else is there.

Comment: Anyone?? Please help... :-/